# itextsharp and xmlworker: "display:none" is not working

Tags: itext, xmlworker

This html:

```
  <div style="display: none">Hey</div>
```

When converted to PDF using **iTextSharp** and **xmlworker** is not hiding the div as it should, so the PDF ends up being a blank page with the text "Hey" in it.

Any workaround for hiding elements?

**Note:** They've removed the xmlworker tester they previously had in itextpdf.com

**Note:**  I'm actually using a wrapper library called MvcRazorToPdf which uses iTextSharp and xmlworker

Comment: "They've removed the xmlworker tester they previously had in itextpdf.com" - yes, it is replaced by pdfHTML, which is an iText 7 add-on. No new features will be added to iText 5 or XMLWorker.

Comment: how can I test that "pdfHTML" will parse "display: none" correctly (ie: by not displaying in the generated pdf)?

Comment: I think you are looking for the new demo? http://demo.itextsupport.com/pdfhtmldemo/

Comment: Oh and I think that MvcRazorToPdf isn't updated yet to be able to use iText 7 and pdfHTML, so you would have to talk to those developers.